# SAGA hydrological analysis in QGIS 2.8 on Mac

Tags: qgis, saga, hydrology

I am running QGIS 2.8 on a Mac machine and I want to calculate the catchment area using SAGA - Catchment Area. It starts running but after a while when QGIS wants to open the generated files there is an error message that QGIS cannot open the files:

```
Oooops! The following output layers could not be open

Name for output filled (flooded) elevation raster map:
/var/folders/g1/r0fk8c2j5ddf7p5jf_1x851w0000gn/T/processing/b30a24aad2ba451abc6875ff7ec46740/filled.tif

Name for output flow direction raster map: 
/var/folders/g1/r0fk8c2j5ddf7p5jf_1x851w0000gn/T/processing/93e5878769d84ebc981bfb3721b1a861/direction.tif

Name for output sink-watershed raster map:
```

In contrast the  SAGA - Channel Network and drainage basin analysis fully works. What is wrong here?

Comment: Are you just running the tool straight, or as part of a model/processing chain?  I seem to recall having this sort of issue using the exact same SAGA cachement area when using it inside a processing chain, which required a hacky workaround.